# file or database for fast reading, infrequent updating/inserting?

Tags: php, javascript, database, json, file-io

My website relies on data made up of 6 "columns" and 200 "rows" which will need to be updated a few times an hour, but will be read often. Can I gain any speed by storing the data in a file rather than a database? The file would be recreated with fresh data by a serverside script a couple times an hour (or as necessary), and would be JSON encoded. My plan is to then load the contents through an AJAX call to the file instead of POST every time to a php script which reads the database. Thanks.

Comment: JSON is a bad format for random writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a flat table, such a small table will be plenty fast.  If this is a more extensive query, I suggest caching the database result instead.

Look into using [Memcached](http://memcached.org/), or some other cache method (which could be a file as you suggest, but that is typically a hassle).